# Initialising an Object and Saving to DB using SpringJPAData is resulting in Null when used inside TestNG @BeforeTest Block

Tags: java, testng

The TestNG BeforeTest has the following code:

```
public void loadAuthorData() {
    int i = 0;
    while (i <= 5) {
        Author author = new Author(fs.name().firstName(), fs.name().lastName(), fs.number().numberBetween(1, 10));
        authorSpringDataRepository.save(author);
        i++;
    }
}
```

This gives me the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "in.sritaj.jpaandhibernate.repository.AuthorSpringDataRepository.save(Object)" because "this.authorSpringDataRepository" is null

**Why is this initialization failing?**

Also, the same block of code works absolutely fine when used inside TestNG @BeforeMethod block

```
 @BeforeMethod
    public void loadAuthorData(){
        int i = 0;
        while(i<=5){
            Author author = new Author(fs.name().firstName(), fs.name().lastName(), fs.number().numberBetween(1, 10));
            authorSpringDataRepository.save(author);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Further Details
**Test Class:**

```
@SpringBootTest
public class AuthorSpringDataRepositoryTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private AuthorSpringDataRepository authorSpringDataRepository;

    private Faker fs = new Faker();

    @BeforeMethod
    public void loadAuthorData(){
        int i = 0;
        while(i<=5){
            Author author = new Author(fs.name().firstName(), fs.name().lastName(), fs.number().numberBetween(1, 10));
            authorSpringDataRepository.save(author);
            i++;
        }
    }
    
 @Test
    public void findAllStudentsUsingJPQLQuery(){
        
        List<Author> authors = authorSpringDataRepository.findAllAuthors();
    }
}
```

**RepositoryClass:**

```
public interface AuthorSpringDataRepository extends CrudRepository<Author, Integer> {

    @Query("from Author")
    List<Author> findAllAuthors();

}
```

**Entity Class:**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int ID;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "books_published")
    private int booksPublished;

    public Author(String firstName, String lastName, int booksPublished){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.booksPublished = booksPublished;
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you initializing `authorSpringDataRepository` ? What configurations are you using for this test class ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos

I have updated the description for your questions, as mentioned the configuration is working with Annotation - BeforeTest which I verified but not with Annotation - BeforeTest. Not sure if there is some limitation or property from TestNG of which I am not aware of.

Thank You

Comment: So you mean that replacing the `@BeforeMethod` with `@Test` will cause the NPE?

Comment: I would recommend enabling the logs in debug mode to see what `@SpringBootTest` is actually initializing the test when you run it. If you repository class is null that means whatever is running this test is not reading configurations correctly OR you have a configuration on your abstract Class that is causing SpringBootTest to not properly initialize the context of your application. 
It could be for instance that you are setting a specific package for Spring components to be initialized and that doesn't include this class.

Comment: @Bahij.Mik the issue is with BeforeTest, it causes the NPE, BeforeMethod the same code works fine.